# Docker Fails due to Node.js not installed when running compiling assets in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I'm trying to run docker-compose up but it when running the entrypoint at this line:

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

The error is: `Node.js not installed. Please download and install Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/`

My Dockerfile installs node so I'm not sure what the issue is.

I've tried a bunch of different Docker file setups and keep getting the same error. Can anyone see how I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

Docker file:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ruby:3.0.4

ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider"


RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client python curl apt-transport-https && \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y yarn

WORKDIR /eclipse
COPY Gemfile /eclipse/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /eclipse/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

RUN echo "Install webpacker ----"
RUN bundle exec rails webpacker:install \
    rails webpacker:compile

# Entrypoint.sh will be run every time the container starts.
COPY /bin/entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Configure the main process to run when running the image
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Compile assets ----"
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

echo "Create database ----"
bundle exec rake db:create

echo "Rake database ----"
bundle exec rake db:migrate

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid

# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

When faced with something like this I generally comment everything from the failing line forward.  Then I fire up the docker container and try to execute the first thing I commented out.  That usually points the way.

Often it turns out I'm installing an ancient version of something I didn't expect.  Of course you're installing node 14 - which is pretty long in the tooth at this point.

In your specific case, I recommend ditching webpacker if this is a new app.  If it is an existing app I recommend migrating to https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker - which is at least somewhat maintained and updated.